# Which sequence should be follow to synchronize code (commit and update) using Egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, conflict, egit

I am quite new with Egit (An Eclipse plugin for git).

I am getting weird errors (like dirty tree, conflict exception) while synchronizing code when there is conflict between local file and remote file.

So which sequence I should follow for use git in better way?

Right now I am performing following steps:

1. Fetching
2. Merging (in this step I am getting errors using Team synchronization.)
3. Add to Git index (in case there is conflict)
4. Committing

Please help me better way if any.

Answer (score 0):

That seems correct, as described in the "[Resolving a merge conflict](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resolving_a_merge_conflict)" of the [EGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

This [EGit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#team_mergeconflicts) adds the following tips:

> Use the Git staging view to find the conflicting files, in large projects that is usually faster than navigating the Package Explorer view.

The rest follows what you are doing:

> Once you have manually merged the changes, select `Team → Add` from the context menu of the resource to mark the conflicts as resolved and commit the merge resolution via `Team → Commit`.